# Ajax Search Form Div Pagination - PHP - CakePHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cakephp, pagination

I have traveled many articles Stack OverFlow but none have solved my problem. I just want to use Ajax with Cake php to refresh a DIV containing the results of my pagination.

Note:
I included the jQuery library.
I called the RequestHandler component:

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler');

public function beforeFilter() {
    if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
        $this->layout=null;
        Configure::write('debug', 0);
    }
}
```

I checked the presence of a "ajax.ctp" in the layout folder

Here is my search function:

```
public function searchIndex(){
        //debug($this->request->data); die;

        $search = $this->request->data['Concessionnaire']['search'];

        $this->Paginator->settings = array(
            'conditions' => array('Concessionnaire.ville LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
            'limit' => 5
        );
        $data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Concessionnaire');
        $this->set('concessionnaires', $data);
        $this->render('index');

    }
```

Views :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="panel">
            <h4>Recherchez une ville :</h4>
            <?php echo $this->Form->create('Concessionnaire',array('id' => 'textBox', 'type' => 'post','url' => array('controller' => 'concessionnaires', 'action' => 'searchIndex'))); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('search', array('label'=>"",'placeholder'=>'Tapez le nom d\'une ville, puis la touche Entree de votre clavier' ,'id'=>'search')); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>      

<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="panel" id="conssR">
            <!-- generation vignettes -->
            <?php foreach ($concessionnaires as $concessionnaire): ?>
                <div class="panel conssPanel radius"> 
                    <h4><b><?php echo h($concessionnaire['Concessionnaire']['nom']); ?></b></h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="large-6 columns" style="padding-left: 70px; font-size: 20px;">
                            <?php echo h($concessionnaire['Concessionnaire']['adresse']); ?><br>
                            <?php echo h($concessionnaire['Concessionnaire']['cp']); ?>
                            <?php echo h($concessionnaire['Concessionnaire']['ville']); ?>
                        <!-- <p>It's a little ostentatious, but useful for important content.</p> -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="large-6 columns" style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
                            Tel: <?php echo h($concessionnaire['Concessionnaire']['tel']); ?><br>
                            Site:  <?php echo h($concessionnaire['Concessionnaire']['website']); ?>
                        </div>  
                    </div>

                    <?php
                        // $map_id = "map_canvas";
               //           $marker_id = 1;
               //           $position = "rue du depot, 62000 ARRAS";
               //           echo $this->GoogleMap->addMarker($map_id, $marker_id, $position);
                    ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

I want to reload the DIV "#conssR" with the string results entered in the form "Concessionnaires". For now , when i write something and valid, the controller show me the result by refreshing the page but I just want to recharge the DIV.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: And how you are making ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

```
   $this->Paginator->options(array(
        'update' => '#conssR',
        'evalScripts' => true
    ));
```

The code above is not part of function it is part of view files which are in View folder and it creates the proper JavaScript to update the div.

Check : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html
It is a helper and helper code goes in your view

```
  if($this->request->is('ajax'))
  {
       $this->render('/Elements/ajax');
  }
```

The above code is used to render ajax.ctp in View/Elements folder which you are not doing at the moment.

Comment: First, thank you for your reply!

I find it hard to grasp the progress of AJAX in CakePHP.

  For now, I think I understand that a trigger event, so the "submit" of my "search" field, I sent form infos to my controller that is waiting for "Ajax" type.

It processes informations and register them in "ajax.ctp" which is used to update my DIV.

Now I can not apply this scheme. A little help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First - you will need to link next button , page button all using paginator helper , link of which i have already provided.

Comment: second - You will need to set a different view for your ajax.

Comment: Why I can not use validation with the "Enter" key to activate?

In addition, your answers are too confusing for me to move on.

Can someone give me an example applicable to my situation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well you can you will have to write javascript on your own in that case, instead of using a builtin